# php check time and date

Tags: php

hello this is working fine for me but i think it can be more simple can anyone help me with this code for checking the time and date entered by user

```
    function ckeck_date($sug_date, $sug_time)
    {
        if ($sug_date[0] == NULL)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($sug_date); $i++)
            {
                if ($this->_totimestamp($sug_date[$i], $sug_time[$i]) < mktime(23, 59, 59, date('m'), date('d') - 1, date('Y')))
                {
                 $x=false;
                }
                else $y=true;
            }

        }
        if(isset($x))
        {
        return $x*$y;
        } 
else return true;

    }
```

Comment: What is this, can you elaborate it ?

Comment: the user can enter some dates and times for a meeting and this function check each date to make sure the user doesn't use old dates just from the current date and the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, take your date and time

```
 $str = '2012-06-15 11:12:23'; // OR '15-06-2012 11:12:23'

if ( strtotime( $str ) > time( ) ) {
  // Your time is greater than current time
}
```

Comment: this working great but i want to shorten the returns i mean i want a less coding is that possible ?

Comment: I'd say a single line if statement is short enough. Why do you need to do this in less code?

Answer (score 0):

For date you can use:

[checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)

With [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) you can create `int` from string and compare them if they are in the future (if you compare against `now`)

```
$today = strtotime(date("Y-m-d")); // today's date
$userd = strtotime("2012-10-16");  // users input

if ($userd > $today){ 
   $valid = "yes"; 
} else { 
   $valid = "no"; 
}
```

If I am right you can add the time to the input as well, but you need to check the php documentation on this for correct date-time format

shorter:

```
if (strtotime($userdate) > strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))){ 
   $valid = "yes"; 
}
```

Comment: i need to see if the date entered by the user is not an old date

Comment: updated answer. provided that your user input is a string, use strtotime to convert it and check it against current date and time

Comment: ok it works fine but i want to shorten the returns i mean i want a less coding is that possible ?